# WebApi hosted on Console App in self-contained .NET Core not working

Tags: asp.net-web-api

The below code builds but does not work. When I run the code, it builds and host's the API @ http://localhost:5000 but when I try to access the same form my browser using http://localhost:5000/api/test, it does not work? What am I missing?

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace ConsoleAppCoreV2
{
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }

    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }

    public class TestController
    {
        [HttpGet("api/test")]
        public object Test()
        {
            return new
            {
                message = "First test",
                time = DateTime.Now
            };
        }

    }
}
}
```

**ConsoleAppCoreV2.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="1.1.0-preview1-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.0-preview1-final" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Is there any working example of a WebApi hosted on Console App in self-contained .NET Core (be it core 1.1 or 2.0 preview)?

Answer (score -1):

You should put the TestController class outside the Programme class.